# How do I get the route scope from the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have something like this set up in my config/routes.rb:

```
  scope "/admin" do
    resources :users
  end
```

I understand that from /admin/users,

```
params[:controller]
```

would be "users"

My question is, is there something like the above that would give me "admin" when in a controller under the "/admin" scope?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have never used nested routes, but from my experience, you could do `scope "/:type" do`. You could then get the type with `params[:type]`.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass parameter that you want to add as scope into your rails routes. see below example

```
scope "/:admin" do
  resources :users
end
```

While you are calling users index path just pass value of admin parameter also. as per below:

```
users_path(admin: "Super")
```